# I want to delete items from firebase database using javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

You can see the image which item i want to delete[image]

[image]

The code of fetch is give below

```
var dbImages = firebase.database().ref("images");

  dbImages.on("value", function(images){

    if(images.exists()){
        var categorieshtml = ""; 
        images.forEach(function(image){

            console.log(image.val().title);
            
            categorieshtml += "<tr>";

            //for category name
            categorieshtml += "<td>";
            categorieshtml += image.key;
            categorieshtml += "</td>";

            //for category description
            categorieshtml += "<td>";
            categorieshtml += image.val().title;
            categorieshtml += "</td>";

             categorieshtml += "<td>";
            categorieshtml += image.val().desc;
            categorieshtml += "</td>";
            
            //for category thumbnail
            categorieshtml += "<td> <img width='250' height='150' src='";
            categorieshtml += image.val().url;
            categorieshtml += "' /></td>";

        
            categorieshtml += "<td>";
            categorieshtml += "<button id='btn-delete' onclick='delete_row("+image.key+")'>Remove</button>"
            categorieshtml += "</td>";

            
            categorieshtml += "</tr>";


        });

        $("#images").html(categorieshtml);
    }

});




function delete_row(childKey) { 



 firebase.database().ref().child('images/' + childKey + '/').remove();

  alert('row was removed');
  reload_page();
}
```

I want to delete node which given in image using button.
I can easily fetch the value but the delete button is not working please help guys.
I want to delete the item from the Firebase real-time database by clicking the button in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes around the argument in the call to `delete_row` here:

```
categorieshtml += "<button id='btn-delete' onclick='delete_row("+image.key+")'>Remove</button>"
```

If you check the generated HTML, you'll see that it looks like this:

```
delete_row(-N2j...JIWFH)
```

The argument here is interpreted as a token/variable, instead of as a literal string value.

To fix this, add yet another pair of quotes in your code:

```
categorieshtml += "<button id='btn-delete' onclick='delete_row(\'"+image.key+"\')'>Remove</button>"
```

Comment: After using your code when i click its show this error in console :- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Interesting. This is definitely the problem though, so you might want to search for [how to nest quotes in HTML attributes](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+nest+quotes+in+HTML+attributes) for the exact syntax.

Comment: But when i used this it working :-  categorieshtml +=  '<button type="button" onClick="delete_row(\'' + image.key + '\')">Remove</button>'

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @AmitYadav. I don't immediately see the difference in the two snippets, so can you suggest an edit to the answer to fix any typo I have in there?

Comment: i know their is no difference between this two snippets, but its working. You can use this code fix the above code :- categorieshtml += '<button type="button" onClick="delete_row(\'' + image.key + '\')">Remove</button>'

Comment: Not sure I follow Amit, but as long as you got it working . Did the explanation I gave about needing quotes around the `image.key` value make sense then?

Comment: yes it makes sense